# Ionic 2 mouseover event to highlight elements

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Is there any possibilities, to simulate mouseover event in Ionic 2? as far as i know, it doesnt support the angular ng-mouseover.
(I need it to highlight some dom element with move over my finger)

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#gestures I think you are looking for the **press** event (or the **tap** event). Press works with a longer delay, so you may use **tap**

Comment: I tryed them, but i have a table, with multiple elements, and need to highlight some of them, with one mousedown, and that gestures working other way. 
If you trigger a pan event, and moves your mouse, its just detect the element you pushed, but not that one, you panned over.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. The event exists, you just need to properly use it. Can you please post some sample code and the desired behavior?